# How to change column names in the resultset by comparing with other resultset values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can we store select query result in a variable and iterate every item of that variable.For example

```
select labelname from controlType
--gives me
labelname
----------
Employee Name
Employee Address
IsActive
DOB
----------
```

I have another table `targetTable` whose coulmns are
  `EmployeeName,

   EmployeeAddress,

   IsActvie,

   DOB`.

You can see these are the same columns that i got from the resultset except white spaces. I want to select all column of `targetTable` with formatted names as in the resultset. For eg should get `'Employee Name'` instead of `EmployeeName`.

This is just an example. In my current scenario I dont know how many column are there and what is resultset. My idea was to store resultset in variable and do some logic while selecting columns of target table. How it can be done. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Table` Variable to store the columns you need to select. Here's a nice tutorial on Table Variables. http://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx

Then construct the SQL Statement Dynamically by looping through the column-names that are in the table variable.

Finally, use `EXEC` or `sp_executesql` to execute the dynamic sql you just generated. Here's an example: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 0):

No need to have any variable you can just use following query and insert all record in `#Temp` variable and then loop through it

```
Select Id,labelname Into #Temp from controlType
Declare @Id int

While (Select Count(*) From #Temp) > 0
 Begin

Select Top 1 @Id = Id From #Temp

--insert your logic here

Delete #Temp Where Id = @Id

End
```

Comment: Didnt get u what do you mean by formatted columns from targetable

Comment: How do i change column EmpName with 'Emp Name'

Comment: thats quite strange, how would u come to know that where to put spaces?

Comment: Empname from Target table and 'Emp Name' from resultset in your answer temp table. Please go through my full question. It is not only about iterating but also using by comparing text of column

Comment: Pardon me, but I believe I am not able to understand your requirement thoroughly